# R Markdown double spacing

Tags: r-markdown

I'm writing a scientific paper (pdf) with R Markdown. The problem is that a want to apply double spacing with `header-includes:
  \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing` but it does not work.

Then there comes this error message:

```
tlmgr search --file --global "/setspace.sty"

tlmgr.pl: Remote repository is newer than local (2018 < 2019)
Cross release updates are only supported with
 update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
! LaTeX Error: File `setspace.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you installed TeXLive your self or via tinytex?

Comment: I am currently installing TeXLive

Comment: If you has previously used tinytex, it would have been easier to use `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()`, c.f. FAQ 11 in https://yihui.name/tinytex/faq/.